# Fully expand a QTreeView representing a QFileSystemModel

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtreeview

I am using to QTreeView to display the contents of a directory. It works as expected, except I want to be able to display it with all the hierarchies open. I was hoping that the QTreeView.expandAll() method would do that but it actually doesn't seem like the ModelItems for the subdirectorie actually exist before expanding the root ones.
What do I need to do in order to view my directory structure fully expanded?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

    self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.treeView = QtGui.QTreeView(self)
        self.treeView.setGeometry(0,0, 600, 800)
        self.model = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
        self.path = "/opt"
        self.model.setRootPath(self.path)
        self.treeView.setModel(self.model)
        self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.model.index(self.path))
        self.treeView.expandAll()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle('Toggle button')
        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've gotten the desired result by doing a os.walk and manually doing a setRootPath on that directory, as follows, but I wonder if there is a more "built-in" Qt way to go.

```
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.path):
        self.model.setRootPath(root)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, are you sure you want to do that? `QFileSystemModel` loads items lazily for [a reason](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemmodel.html#caching-and-performance). Querying a full directory tree might be taxing and time consuming.

For a more Qt version, you can use [directoryLoaded](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemmodel.html#directoryLoaded) signal to fetch and expand the sub-folders as they arrive:

```
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

    self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.treeView = QtGui.QTreeView(self)
        self.treeView.setGeometry(0,0, 600, 800)
        self.model = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
        self.path = "/opt"
        self.model.setRootPath(self.path)
        self.treeView.setModel(self.model)
        self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.model.index(self.path))
        # self.treeView.expandAll()  Not needed

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle('Toggle button')

        self.model.directoryLoaded.connect(self._fetchAndExpand)

        self.show()

    def _fetchAndExpand(self, path):
        index = self.model.index(path)
        self.treeView.expand(index)  # expand the item
        for i in range(self.model.rowCount(index)):
            # fetch all the sub-folders
            child = index.child(i, 0)
            if self.model.isDir(child):
                self.model.setRootPath(self.model.filePath(child))
```

**Note**: For a large directory tree, this might freeze the GUI for a period of time. That's not because of the model, but rather the view is doing quite a bit of work for each expanded item and things add up.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
    if choice != 1:
        self.model.directoryLoaded.connect(self.expand)
    else:
        pass
        
    
def expand(self):
    self.emp.treeViewFolderView.expandAll()
```

`directoryLoaded` was the solution!